# How do I show the diff in a single window in fugitive.vim?

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

Best I can tell, all the diff commands in Fugitive open up a split window. Is there a way to just show the added/deleted/modified lines in a *single* window -- i.e., show the current file's changes (since the last commit, or, ideally, since an arbitrary commit) without opening a window with the index version?

Answer (score 3):

If the unified/inline diff is what you mean by a single window, you can use Fugitive `:Git diff @ -- %` command to just show the added/deleted/modified lines of the current file since the last commit in a new single window.

If you are looking for intra-line diff, as the opposite of side-by-side diff, just like VSCode's inline diff view [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enNsU.png) (set `diffEditor.renderSideBySide` option to `false`) or GitHub's Unified diff display [Example](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/commit/8fd6bad4a4dfbad85d57d03e5ba12a00effbfe8c?diff=unified) ... Unfortunately, Vim doesn't support that.

If you only want to show the changes since the last commit, just run `:G` command, here is the unified diff format. Otherwise, you can use git's `diff` command by Fugitive, just run `:G diff BASE_COMMIT` to show the unified/inline diff against an arbitrary commit. For example, `:G diff HEAD`, `:G diff @~2 -- %`, `:G diff f88a3b8` and so on. For details to see git docs ([`git diff --help`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)) and fugitive docs ([`:help fugitive`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/62f42f013d866139fa23068ac2651b3f7e05a56f/doc/fugitive.txt), [`:h fugitive-object`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/62f42f013d866139fa23068ac2651b3f7e05a56f/doc/fugitive.txt#L595)).

> Is there a way to just show the added/deleted/modified lines in a single window ?

**Solution other than fugitive**: If you only want to show the unified/inline diff highlighting just in the current window, maybe you need other plugins see [IDE-like inline diff highlighting in Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/23170/41821). About the [vim-gitgutter plugin](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter), as for your question, jump to the doc of [vimdiff](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter#vimdiff). You can also specify an arbitrary commit to compare against by the `g:gitgutter_diff_base` variable (e.g. `:let g:gitgutter_diff_base = 'HEAD~2'`). Then you can run `:GitGutterFold` command to see the current file's changes without opening any other windows. Now you can use `:GitGutterPrevHunk` and `:GitGutterNextHunk` to jump between your change hunks, and `:GitGutterPreviewHunk` to show the hunk details. Of course, there is also a `:GitGutterDiffOrig` command here, just like the Fugitive `:Gdiffsplit` command. For convenience, see [`:help gitgutter-mappings`](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter/blob/00df1089b6267f47c7c0f13536789feb9db1e65b/doc/gitgutter.txt#L249). For more features and details see it's documentations, it will be helpful to use it with vim-fugitive.